# Behaviour of deepcopy while changing object to be copied

Tags: python, python-2.7

If an object that's being copied (using the deepcopy function from python 2.7's copy library) by thread A is changed, concurrently, by thread B, what is expected to happen?

EDIT:
The object to be changed is a dictionary, and the change would be the removal of a single key from it. In my case, copying either the old dictionary or the new one would be ok - I just wanted to assure that weirder indefinite states wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code like will not only break the interpreter because they have put a GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) in Python.
So, you will still have your copied object in an indefinite state, but thanks to the GIL, each of the sub-objects inside it will be itself a consistent and complete Python object.  **Which** sub-objects will end up in the copied state are just a matter of chance, however.

If, as you say, the other thread will change a single dictionary value, and it is not important where your copy will end up with the old or new value, there is no danger at all: Python ensures the integrity of the dictionary object in any case.

If you have multiple possible concurrent changes on a complex object, use a manual [lock](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) to ensure one state you are "seeing" as the state the copy will be.

Comment: "Bad code like this is why they have to put a GIL in Python" - no, there's a GIL because the interpreter itself has all sorts of thread-unsafe design.

Comment: yeah - you are right. but it makes one thinking of extending the GIL to make functions atomic, like they are in javascript.  I should rephrase anyway.

Comment: what do you mean by 'indefinite state'?

Comment: @jsbueno, i'm sorry, my original description of the problem wasn't clear enough. Would it be possible to answer it again, considering the edit made?

Comment: The you are - I reiterated the concept: there is no problem.